# Execute a function to return a value on a loop until that function returns False - Python

Tags: python

I have a function that moves a file from one server to another. The function returns the file name when executed or it returns False if no file was transferred.

I would like to call this function on a loop until it returns False. I also need to access the returned value (file name) each time the function is called. I can do one or the other but I am having trouble doing both. Here's what I am trying to accomplish in pseudo-code:

Function that moves file (this will not change):

```
def move_first_matching_file():
    try:
        # find the first file that matches a wildcard file name
        # move the file from remote server to local server
        # delete file from remote server
        return name_of_file
    except:
        return False
```

Calling the above function in other module (this needs work):

```
while move_first_matching_file() as name_of_file is not False:
    # process name_of_file
```

I need to accomplish the while loop above but also access the returned file name. How do I do this? My code above clearly does not work, but it outlines what I would like  to achieve.

Comment: `while move_first_matching_file(): process file` should work

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "Unclear what you're asking" since I don't know which part we're supposed to answer. How to design the return statements? What code should go in the commented parts of the try block? If both, this is too broad.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist isn't he asking "code a function that process a file until false is reach"?

Comment: @Whitefret That doesn't answer my question. Do we show the pattern, as Daniel Roseman has done, for creating the return value of such a function, or do we also fill in the parts that process the file? The latter is too broad.

Comment: `I have a function that moves a file from one server to another. The function returns the file name when executed or it returns False if no file was transferred.` seems to me he got the function for reading the file ;)

Comment: @Daniel Roseman has given exactly what I'm looking for. No code is needed to process the file. I intentionally left that out. The trouble I was having was the combination of 1) returning the file name and 2) executing the function until it returns False. His answer achieves both of those results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do things like that in Python, as assignment is always a statement. The usual pattern is:

```
while True:
    name_of_file = move_first_matching_file()
    if not name_of_file:
        break
    ...
```

Comment: No need for `while true: ... break` if the function returns `truthy` - it returns a filename (and from what I know, filenames can't be zero length), or `False`. See @Whitefret's comment on the question.

Comment: @dwanderson actually he is right, because op wants to keep the name of the file to process it after. another solution would be to assign the value within the loop

Comment: Ah, right, silly me. Sorry about that, getting ahead of myself!

Comment: Thanks Dan! Exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

As said in comment, you can also do

```
filename = move_first_matching_file()
while filename:
    # process file
    # call the function again and reassing the filename
    filename = move_first_matching_file()
```

Because your function send a string if successful (which always stands for true), and false if unsuccessful.
So the loop while break if the function fails, but goes on if a file name is found